# Turn an object into an array of single-key objects (with underscore?)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, underscore.js

I have an object like this: `var o = { foo:"foo", bar:"bar" }`

I'd like an output like this: `[ { foo:"foo" }, { bar:"bar" } ]`

I'd like the code to be concise, and usually underscore provides that.  I've gotten this far...

```
_.map(_.pairs(o), function(pair) { return { pair[0] : pair[1] }; });
```

But of course I can't use an evaluated expression as the key in that code.  I think I can do this...

```
_.map(_.pairs(o), function(pair) {
    var kv = {};
    kv[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    return kv;
});
```

But I was hoping to be concise.  And that ain't.  Seems like there's a simple one-liner out there that I'm too dumb to see.  Is there?

PS - I want this because I want to turn the object into a mongo query disjunction, like this:

```
{ $or: [ { foo:"foo" }, { bar:"bar" } ] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your oneliner works in ES6 if you change `pair[0]` to `[pair[0]]`:

```
_.map( _.pairs( o ), pair => ( { [pair[0]] : pair[1] } ) );
```

You can also do it in ES6 without using underscore like this:

```
Object.keys( o ).map( key => ( { [key]: o[key] } ) );
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w99dvxwq/2/)

Or slightly shorter with underscore:

```
_.keys( o ).map( key => ( { [key]: o[key] } ) );
```

or:

```
_.map( o, (value, key) => ( { [key]: value } ) ) );
```

Comment: _.mapObject is prob a better way

Comment: Thanks.  Both ideas work well, and I think I'll use the Object.keys idea.

Comment: @user1272965 I just edited another version, which I actually like better than `Object.keys` if you're already using underscore. I found out that `_.map` works on objects, so that last version is pretty nice.

Comment: Even better.  Much obliged.  A little bit scared of the new => syntax, I opted for an older-school version or your last suggestion `_.map( o, function(value, key) { return { [key]: value }; });`

Comment: @user1272965 Just to let you know the `[key]` syntax is called "computed object property names" and is newer than the `=>` syntax for arrow functions. I don't think there are any environments that will support `[key]` without supporting `=>`. Though I'm assuming you are running in `node.js` since you are querying a database, in which case you don't have to worry about compatibility unless you have some reason to stay compatible with older versions of node. If it works, it works :) Arrow functions can also make your code simpler, because of the lexical `this` binding they use.

Answer (score 1):

[Working example](https://jsbin.com/luhoguv/1/edit?js,console)
You should probably use `_.mapObject` for this:

```
var a = _.mapObject(o, function(val, key) {
  return {val: key};
});
```

then you can wrap that in an array:

```
var final = [a]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  This produced a result not quite of the form I hoped, with an extra layer of keys.

Comment: More specifically, mapObject produces an object, not an array.  And this code produces `{ foo: { val: 'foo' }, bar: { val: 'bar' } }`.  But thanks again for the help.